# Mouseover on a ListItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Was wondering if anyone know how to implement a Mouseover component for a Material UI ListItem (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list)?  Since "SecondaryText" only allows 2 lines, I am trying to find a way to display the rest of the data (Author, Badge, Team, etc.).

This is my List:

```
 <List>
              {trendingPosts.map(trendingPost => 
                <ListItem
                  leftAvatar={<Avatar src={constants.ASSET_URL + "resources/img/user-default.jpg"} />}
                  //rightIconButton={rightIconMenu}
                  primaryText={trendingPost.title} 
                  secondaryText={
                    <p>
                      <span style={{color: darkBlack}}>{trendingPost.content}</span><br />
                      {trendingPost.author}<span style={trendingBadge}><img width="5" src="https://img.clipartfest.com/8bcfb3290cdd56968f572b08a125a00b_blue-dot-clip-art-dorothy-clipart-transparent-background_300-300.png" /></span> &gt; {trendingPost.team}
                      <br />
                      {trendingPost.time}
                    </p>
                  }
                  secondaryTextLines={2}
                />

              )}
              </List>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is extend the `ListItem` component and then pass the data down via props.

Something like say a `ListItemWithHover` whose `render` function looks like

```
render(){  
   return(
     <div className="list-item-with-hover">
       <ListItem/>
       <div className="list-item-extension"></div>
     </div>
    }
}
```

Then I guess you can use css in this manner

```
.list-item-with-hover{
  position:relative;
}

.list-item-with-hover:hover .list-item-extension{
  display:block;
}

.list-item-extension{
  position:absolute;
  right:-100%;
  top:0
  display:none;
}
```

The `list-item-with-hover` refers to the `ListItem` wrapper and the `list-item-extension` is where you will keep the other information you want to display. The `list-item-extension` with the current values will be to the right and is hidden by default. On hovering over the `list-item-with-hover`it will display.

Of course you will have to pass the `trendingPost` object as a prop to the new `ListItemWithHover` component so you can use it there.

```
<List>
      {trendingPosts.map(trendingPost => <ListItemWithHover trendingPost=trendingPost/>)}
</List>
```